# How to iterate over table in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I would like to iterate over the rows in my Payment table. User chose for what month and year has wants to book and I want to check in the each raw if this house was booked for this year and month. I want to compare if

```
HouseID == chosenHouseID && BookingMonth == chosenBookingMonth &&     
BookingYear==chosenBookingYear.
```

If this is true it should pop out message box with info that house was already booked for this month. Also if user chose more than one month i.e. numMonths would be 3, it should increment value of the month (which is a text) it should go to the next value (if there is no next value then it should do mod 12) and do the checking again. Maybe it will be necessary to switch data type of BookingMonth to numeric?

However I hope I was clear what I want to do. I have experience with Java, C, Python and Visual Basic, but I did not do much in Access so it is quite confusing. I could not find the any useful info how to perform this operation. Please advise me on my issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you definitely should store the [BookingMonth] as numeric. Maintaining a "month" column as text will be a nuisance in the long run, since "August"<"January" and "12"<"2". You'd have to do at least a certain amount of juggling to convert the text values to numeric values, so make like easy for yourself and just maintain them as numeric. (Note that you can always *format* them as text if you want to use them in reports.)

As for your search requirements, if the user supplies a [chosenBookingYear], [chosenBookingMonth], and [numberOfMonthsToBook] then you can use the VBA `DateAdd` function to derive [endOfBookingYear] and [endOfBookingMonth] safely, accounting for "next year" values...

```
endOfBookingYear = Year(DateAdd("m", numberOfMonthsToBook - 1, DateSerial(chosenBookingYear, chosenBookingMonth, 1)))
```

...and...

```
endOfBookingMonth = Month(DateAdd("m", numberOfMonthsToBook - 1, DateSerial(chosenBookingYear, chosenBookingMonth, 1)))
```

Finally, to perform the lookup without looping through individual rows you can concatenate [BookingYear] and [BookingMonth] together to create something like "2013/05" using...

```
BookingYear & "/" & Format(BookingMonth, "00")
```

...so then you can create a SELECT query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Payment
WHERE HouseID = chosenHouseID AND
    (
        (BookingYear & "/" & Format(BookingMonth, "00"))
            BETWEEN (chosenBookingYear & "/" & Format(chosenBookingMonth, "00"))
                AND (endOfBookingYear & "/" & Format(endOfBookingMonth, "00"))
    )
```